Recommendation from professor in a different field for grad school
Somewhat related to this question, but different.
I am going to apply for grad school in the US soon and will need three recommendation letters. I have had two good research experiences (one on my Master's thesis and another on a summer program) related to my field, theoretical particle physics - this is also what I want to do a PhD in.
The problem is the third letter. As an undergraduate, I didn't get the chance to work on any particle physics projects as I lacked the background in quantum field theory that one typically needs. Instead, I worked with a professor on nonlinear physics - my work was substantial enough for a first-author peer-reviewed publication. I presented a second work (with the same professor) at an international conference (and was the first author on the proceedings too). He also taught me two courses on statistical mechanics and I did very well on both.
Now, I would love to ask this professor for my third letter (and I know for a fact that he'd be delighted to write me a strong letter) - however, his field of research (nonlinear physics and condensed matter theory) is completely different to what I am applying in and he's a very senior professor - so, in most cases, the people I am applying to will not be familiar with him (or so I have been told by my other supervisors).
On the other hand, I have been reading (for example, here) that letters of recommendation from people who simply taught you a course don't count for much even if you do extremely well in that course. I had been thinking about asking the instructors from my graduate level quantum field theory courses for letters (I had done very well on both) but it seems like a waste at this point.
My question is: does a letter of recommendation from a faculty from a completely different field (who has supervised a great project you were on) matter more than a recommendation from a professor who taught you an advanced course that you did really well on? While all the professors know me well, the former professor knows me a huge lot better than the latter ones considering that I worked with him for more than a year.
(Note: I do not study in the US. I come from a South Asian country.)

When I read "completely different field", I assumed you meant a computer scientist for a physics program or equivalent. In this case, having someone in a different area of physics isn't a problem since they are familiar with what it takes to succeed in physics grad school. Since that letter writer can speak effectively about your potential for success in the most informed way, you should have no qualms about asking them.

Thanks - thats what I'll do then.

Actually, in the US, even a recommendation from math, CS, or even English might be fine. But, as you say, another area of physics isn't "different" for this purpose.

Personally, I find that letters from writers in other disciplines frequently (though not always) have a very different idea of what traits stand out as important for my field, often to the applicants detriment.
